# ¿Cómo llenar un TEXTBOX al seleccionar un COMBOBOX?

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

¿Alguien sabrá cómo llenar un `textbox` de **c#** con registros de una base de datos en **MySQL** al seleccionar un registro de un `combobox`?

Hasta el momento puedo hacer que se desplieguen los datos en el `combobox` para poder seleccionar cualquiera pero no tengo idea de como hacer que el `textbox` se llene con el dato complementario de la tabla.

La tabla tiene los siguientes campos:

> IdProovedor
>
> NombreProveedor
>
> Telefono
>
> EMail

En el `combobox` hago que aparezcan los datos del IdProovedor y la intención es en el  `textbox` aparezca el NombreProveedor al elejir su IdProovedor correspondiente en el  `combobox`, no se si me explique bien, pero agradecería mucho si alguien puede auxiliarme con esto.

el código para llamar el combobox es este en una clase implemente lo siguiente:

```
    public void llenarcombo(ComboBox ComboidproveedorCC)
    {
        MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand("seleccionidproveedor1", conectar);
        cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cm);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        ComboidproveedorCC.ValueMember = "IdProveedor";
         ComboidproveedorCC.DataSource=dt;
    }
```

y para mandar a llamar los datos al combobox utilize este codigo:

```
    private void RefrescarCombo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cma.llenarcombo(CBIdProvControl);
    }
```

Agradecería su ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Por qué llenar el textbox con el nombre del proveedor? En su lugar, podrías modificar tu consulta por algo así

`select IdProveedor, NombreProveedor from proveedores`

Y eso lo asignas al combobox

`ComboidproveedorCC.ValueMember = "IdProveedor";
 ComboidproveedorCC.DisplayMember = "NombreProveedor";
 ComboidproveedorCC.DataSource = dt;`

Con eso te ahorrarías tener que llenar el textbox, pues el combobox mostraría directamente el nombre del proveedor.

Si de todos modos quieres llenar el textbox, se haría con

`ComboidproveedorCC_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    textBox1.Text = ComboidproveedorCC.Text;
 }`

Ojalá te sirva.
Saludos!

Comment: Holaa si me funciona esto pero pasa que tengo un datagriewvied y añ seleccionar esto los elementos del data no me los muestra :(

Comment: Perdon, pasa que si me llena el texboxt pero con el IdProveedor pero quisiera que se llenase con el NombreProveedor

Comment: Hay un pequeño error en el código que te puse anteriormente, ya lo corregí, con eso debería trabajar bien.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez este ejemplo te ayude

```
using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
{
    cn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("SELECT nombreProveedor FROM provedor WHERE IdProovedor = @id", cn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(cmbprovedor.SelectedValue));

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if(dr.Read())
    {
        txtpago.Text = Convert.ToString(reader("nombreProveedor"));
    }
}
```

esto lo pones dentro del evento SeelctionChangeCommited del combo de IdProovedor

Answer (score 0):

**NOTA:** Creo que sería mas práctico utilizar las propiedades ValueMember y DisplayMember del Combobox y si estableces las propiedades AutoCompleteMode = SuggestAppend y AutoCompleteSource = ListItems y DropDownStyle = DropDown podrias mostrar y filtrar los nombres de proveedor con su respectivo id proveedor desde el ComboBox sin necesidad de usar el TextBox para mostrar el nombre.

Esto seria algo así

```
public void llenarcombo(ComboBox ComboidproveedorCC)
{
    var query = "SELECT IdProveedor, NombreProveedor FROM Proveedores";
    MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand(query, conectar);
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cm);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    ComboidproveedorCC.ValueMember = "IdProveedor";
    ComboidproveedorCC.DisplayMember = "NombreProveedor";
    ComboidproveedorCC.DataSource=dt;
}
```

**Pero para mostrar el nombre del proveedor al textbox una solución a tu problema seria:**

```
public string SeleccionarProveedor(int IdProveedor) {
    var query = "SELECT NombreProveedor FROM tbProveedores WHERE Proveedor WHERE IdProveedor = " + IdProveedor;
    using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conectar)) {
        var read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if(read.HasRows) {
            if(read.Read()) {
                return read["NombreProveedor"].ToString();
            }
            else{
                throw new Exception("No se encuentra ningún proveedor con el Id Proveedor = " + IdProveedor);
            }
        }
        else{
            throw new Exception("No se encuentra ningún proveedor con el Id Proveedor = " + IdProveedor);
        }
    }
}
```

Luego solo mandas a llamar ese método desde el evento SelectedIndexChanged del ComboBox y cada vez que selecciones otro IdProveedor el mostrará el NombreProveedor en el TextBox.

Quedaría así:

```
private void ComboidproveedorCC_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBoxNombreProveedor.Text = SeleccionarProveedor(int.Parse(ComboidproveedorCC.SelectedValue.ToString()));
}
```